# Bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else', grep termin using ssh

Tags: bash, if-statement, ssh, grep

I'm new to bash, so this could be a simple fix. I'm trying to write a piece of code that allows me to check when jobs have completed on different servers. This is the current block of Code that I've got.

```
#!/bin/bash

boxes=(dm virgil alpha kolp law be corn zira)
Cyan='\033[0;36m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
for box in "${boxes[@]}"; do
    echo ""
    echo -e "${Cyan}${box}${NC}"
    ssh "${box}" "ls -ltr | tail -n 11 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6- "
done

echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

This works ok, and gives the following output.

```
dm
Jan 13 08:47 Model_SNAr_smallbasisset_TCM.chk
Jan 14 09:57 Phoscat_SS_regioazid_subopt.com
Jan 14 09:57 Phoscat_SS_regioazid_subopt.log
Jan 14 09:57 Phoscat_SS_regioazid_subopt.csh
Jan 14 09:57 nohup.out
Feb 4 17:57 Model_SNAr_smallbasisset_wb97xd_sm.com
Feb 4 17:57 Model_SNAr_smallbasisset_b3lyp_sm.com
Feb 4 17:57 Model_SNAr_medbasisset_b3lyp_sm.com
Feb 4 17:58 Model_SNAr_smallbasisset_wb97xd_fp.com
Feb 4 17:58 Model_SNAr_smallbasisset_b3lyp_fp.com
Feb 4 17:58 Model_SNAr_medbasisset_b3lyp_fp.com
```

As you can see, this shows all files, whereas I would like to narrow it down to just certain file extensions, and effectively "grep termin [filename]" in order to determine whether the job has completed normally. Currently my script will show any files that have been created, but not necessarily completed.

By changing

```
"ls -ltr | ..."
```

to

```
"ls -ltr *.log *.out |"
```

I can selectively search file extensions, but where I haven't got any files of that extension in a directory, I get the following which looks messy and I'd like to get rid of.

```
zira
ls: cannot access *.log: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access *.out: No such file or directory
```

To tidy this up, I tried to use an if..else statement, but got the following error.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/$HOME"
boxes=(dm virgil alpha kolp law be corn zira)
Cyan='\033[0;36m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
for box in "${boxes[@]}"; do
    ssh "${box}"
    if [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
        for box in "${boxes[@]}"; do
            echo ""
            echo -e "${Cyan}${box}${NC}"
            ssh "${box}" "ls -ltr *.log *.out | tail -n 11 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6-"
    else
        echo ""
        fi

done

echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"


line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
line 14: `    else'
```

Am I missing something easy, and how would I go about incorporating a "grep termin" style command?

Thanks,

Cal

Comment: The single `ssh "${box}"` before the inner `for` is an error or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a wildcard pattern like *.log doesn't match anything, the shell will return the *literal string* "*.log". You could test for that string explicitly. But a cleaner way is to use

```
    shopt -s nullglob; ls *.log
```

to change the shell's behavior. Then patterns without a match will simply be suppressed, which is what you want.

Older versions of Bourne shell don't support `shopt`, but you can still test if the result of the wildcard is `"*.log"`

Answer (score 1):

`for` is missing the closing `done` (should be right before the `else`)